# Angular: How to route to different components, depending on API response?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular10

I am wondering whether / how it is possible to implement a specific routing strategy in Angular 10.

To explain, take this simplified example:

I have an Angular application with 4 components:

- `StudentListComponent`: Displays list of all students
- `CourseListComponent`: Displays list of all courses
- `StudentComponent`: Displays details about one specific student
- `CourseComponent`: Displays details about one specific course

I would like to achieve the following routing strategy

- `myapp.com/students` routes to "StudentListComponent"
- `myapp.com/courses` routes to "CourseListComponent"
- **`myapp.com/millerh` routes to "StudentComponent" and displays details about student with username "millerh"**
- **`myapp.com/math1` routes to "CourseComponent" and displays details about course with short name "math1"**

The names "millerh" and "math1" are unique, and there is no id that maps to both a student and a course. (EDIT: There will also be no student or course called "students" or "courses")

*Background: The links will be displayed in another application where the links will not be clickable and can not be copy/pasted, thus I want the paths to be as short as possible. Also power users will prefer to directly type out the URL rather than going to the list pages and searching for the student / course they want to see details of.*

**To achieve this, I want to make a backend/API call during routing. The API response will indicate, whether i.e. "millerh" is a student, a course or neither of the two.** Depending on that I want to navigate to the respective component, and pass the name of the student/course along to the component. I would like to avoid a redirect, i.e. from myapp.com/millerh to myapp.com/students/millerh, to avoid having multiple valid paths for the same resource.

How could I achieve this, starting from the out-of-the-box angular routing module?

Thanks very much for any hints and suggestions!

Comment: it isn't right the use of AuthGuard for these cases, but you can do a workaround with that. You can do an API call and navigate the user wherever you want. But I like Elmehdi's answer, you can try like that.

Comment: What if you have a student with a username `students` or a course with a short name `courses`?

Comment: The backend will ensure that there is no conflicts between names of students, names of courses, and static route names. Of course this is a potential source for unintended behaviour, but I am aware of it and will ensure no conflicts. The use case presented here is only an example, the actual use case has a different domain in which I can choose these names by my own.

Comment: You probably don't need the router if you don't show components based on a route format.

Comment: also @Finrod_Amandil what about route resolvers? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-route-resolvers and

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan thanks for the hints to Guards and Resolvers - these are interesting ideas to execute custom code during routing. However, as I understand, both are being attached to a **specific** route mapping to a **specific** component. However, that'd not be possible as I do not know yet which route relates to which component at the time I want to make my API call.

Would it maybe be possible to have a wildcard "match-all" route that links to a fake component, attach a Guard/Resolver to that route and then choose the component in the Guard/Resolver logic?

Comment: Something along the lines of ```{ path: '*', component: FakeComponent, resolve: { route: RouteResolver } }```

Comment: you can store the data for each route and get it in the guard or resolver. https://angular.io/api/router/Route#data

Comment: Oh, of course :) so the path would probably be simply something like `path: ':route'` and then I can simply work with the route name in the resolver/guard. This sounds like a very promising approach, I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I mean you can for example have `{path: '/students', component: ......, data: {key: someNecessary data which needed in the guard } }` and in the guard you can get it `route.data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I have found a working solution that I like quite much: It seems to work well, and does not feel very hacky. It's not really matching exactly any of the posted suggestions - but thanks for all the replies and comments as they really helped me finding the final solution!

The final solution uses in its core a guard implementing CanActivate, combined with `router.resetConfig()` and `router.navigate()` inside the guard.

As an entry point to my solution I use the standard routing module. It's still useful to my use case as there are components that have a single static route.

*file: app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './features/home/home.component';
import { StudentListComponent} from './features/student-list/student-list.component';
import { CourseListComponent} from './features/course-list/course-list.component';
import { LoadingComponent } from './features/loading/loading.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './features/not-found/not-found.component';
import { DynamicRouteGuard } from './guards/dynamic-route.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '/', 
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'students',
    component: StudentListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'courses',
    component: CourseListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    canActivate: [ DynamicRouteGuard ],
    component: LoadingComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The paths /, students, courses, and not-found are normal static routes like in most Angular apps. Any route which does not match these will be treated by the wildcard route at the bottom. That route loads a component which may hold a loading spinner. It will be visible while the Guard makes the API call to the backend asynchronously, to determine which component to load.

*file: dynamic-route.guard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EntityTypeService } from '../../services/entity-type.service';
import { IEntityTypeModel } from '../../models/entity-type.model';
import { EntityType } from '../../models/entity-type.enum';
import { StudentDetailComponent } from '../features/student-detail/student-detail.component';
import { CourseDetailComponent } from '../features/course-detail/course-detail.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DynamicRouteGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private entityTypeService : EntityTypeService,
    private router : Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
    Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    // At this point, only routes with a single path element are considered valid routes.
    if (route.url.length != 1) {
      this.router.navigate(['not-found']);
      return false;
    }

    let path = route.url[0].toString();

    // Ask backend, what kind of entity the requested path matches to
    this.entityTypeService.getEntityTypeForPath(path).subscribe(response => {
      let entityTypeModel = response as IEntityTypeModel;

      // If backend did not recognize path --> redirect to page not found component.
      if (entityTypeModel.entityType === EntityType.Unknown) {
        this.router.navigate(['not-found']);
      }

      // Build a new routes array. Slicing is required as wildcard route
      // should be omitted from the new routes array (risk of endless loop)
      let routes = this.router.config;
      let newRoutes = routes.slice(0, routes.length - 1);

      // Add a new route for the requested path to the correct component.
      switch(entityTypeModel.entityType) {
        case EntityType.Student:
          newRoutes.push({ path: path, component: StudentDetailComponent, data: { resourceName: path } });
          break;
        case EntityType.Course:
          newRoutes.push({ path: path, component: CourseDetailComponent, data: { resourceName: path } });
          break;
        default:
          this.router.navigate(['not-found']);
          return;
      }

      // Reload routes and navigate.
      this.router.resetConfig(newRoutes);
      this.router.navigate([path]);
    });

    // Guard always returns true and loads LoadingComponent while API 
    // request is being executed.
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the guard, the requested route is accessible and an API service can easily be injected. Using that service, the backend looks up the path in the database, and returns an enum value indicating whether its a Student, a Course or neither. Depending on that, a new route is added to the Routes array, for that specific student/course name, linking to the matching component. After that, the routes are reloaded, and the Router can directly navigate to the correct component.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Angular router has any means of distinguishing between millerh being a student and math1 being a course, I think you should go with something like:
`myapp.com/students/millerh`
`myapp.com/courses/math1`

### EDIT

Imagine one of your users want to search of a student, he is gonna type `myapp.com/students/<studentName>`, then the app is gonna navigate to `students` component and the `studentName` is gonna be available as routing params, then you can use `ngOnInit` life cycle hook to make your API call to the students endpoint of you backend.

### EDIT number 2

#### Solution without having to type students/courses in the URL but you will still have have them after the URL resolves

Let's say you don't wanna differentiate between the students route and courses route at first.
Image your user type `myapp.com/<someValue>`, for now you don't know what he is looking for, student or course, at first he is gonna land on your root component, in this component you can use `ngOnInit` to make your API calls.
Start by making an API call to your students endpoint, if there a student, make your app navigate programmatically to `myapp.com/students/<someValue>`.
If no student is found, make an API call to your course endpoint, if there a course, make your app navigate programmatically to `myapp.com/courses/<someValue>`.
Ultimatly there is gonna be a reference to either students of courses in the url, but it is gonna be easier for your users because they can directly type `myapp.com/<someValue>`.

#### Solution without having to type students/courses in the URL and you wont have them in the URL at the end either

Instead of having your students component and your courses in two different pages, you can put them both in one single page, maybe the root component in your case, and instead of redirecting either to `students` or `course`, you can show one or the other depending on which API call returned a value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Of course the Frontend/Angular can not determine this by itself. During routing I want to make a call to my backend which can check the database to figure out whether a specific name is a student or a course (or neither). This is basically the core of my question: How I can make an API call **during** routing

Comment: @Finrod_Amandil I added some explanation to my answer, tell me if you need a live demo as it is gonna take me a bit of time to make it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am familiar with how to achieve the routing pattern you describe, and it will be the option that I will use if I don't get the routing strategy that I described in the question to work. I am specifically wondering whether/how it is possible to achieve the routing without the /students/ part, to shorten the URLs (see question for motivation)

Comment: @Finrod_Amandil I add some more scenarios :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions! They both definitely sound like workable solutions. The second one is currently my favorite solution and I may try that one, having the root component template look something like `<student-detail *ngIf="isStudent"></student-detail><course-detail *ngIf="isCourse"></course-detail>` It's definitely hacky tho, and only workable if Angular really doesnt load the sub-components for which ngIf is false.

Comment: @Finrod_Amandil don't forget to accept my answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: I have not forgotten! I first want to implement a working solution which I will do very soon. I will then either accept your answer if my final solution is based on your suggestions, or write up another answer if it's a different solution.